# Textarea value?

Tags: text, textarea

When I use a text-input type , i can just give it a value and use that, even on another page
example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>">
```

Can I do the same with a textarea?
example :

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="123" name="comments" value="<?php echo $row['comments'];?>" ></textarea>
```

This is my code in where I retrieve an existing row of information from a given ID. The info consists of a name, emailaddress and comments :

```
<form method="post">
        <div class="row gy-2 text-left">
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-auto gy-2">
                    <label>Name</label> <br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['naam'];?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-auto gy-2"> 
                    <label>Email address</label><br>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto gy-2">     
                    <label>Tell me about it</label><br>
                    <style>
                        textarea {resize: none;}
                    </style>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="123" name="comments" value="<?php echo $row['comments'];?>" ></textarea>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto gy-3"> 
                    <button class="btn edit btn-info border border-dark" name="Update">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the textarea element, it goes between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags:

```
<textarea><?php echo $row['comments'];?></textarea>
```

The `<textarea>` element does not use an HTML attribute named `value` like  the `<input>` element does.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attributes

However, when the HTML markup which contains a textarea element is parsed by the browser, an HTMLTextAreaElement object is created. This  *DOM element* object, which represents the state of the textarea element on the web page does have a JavaScript object property named `.value`, which gives access via JavaScript to the text which the textarea element contains.

This JavaScript code logs the text that is contained in a `textarea` element:

`console.info(document.querySelector('textarea').value);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement